# How to drop rows if this row has a certain relationship with other rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example:

```
id          name  label topic date
1008068494  abc   x   animal    20210929
1008068494  abc   x       20210929
1008068494  abc   y       20210929
```

In these three rows, the 2nd row is almost the same as the 1st row, except for the 3rd column, which is empty. In such a case, I want to drop the 2nd row, since the 2nd row is already included in the 1st row.

So my drop condition is that:

```
if a row has a column A whose value is empty, and all other columns' values are the same as another row B, then drop A. This can be seen in a relationship:
    A IS_INCLUDED_IN B
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: There is empty only `topic` column? If is added row `1008068494  abc   x   another    20210929` what is ouput?

Comment: @jezrael, you keep the new row and delete the 2nd row, because this new row is not included in any other rows. And any column can be empty.

Comment: I haven't tested, just to answer your question above.

Comment: thinking - all another columns has values, but possible any columns has NaNs? Is possible create better sample, e.g. 10 rows with more NaNs?

Comment: All NaNs are replaced with '' string. If all other columns are also empty, we still drop this column. This would be really rare, but can still be safely dropped.

Comment: yes, I thinking about logic the best is create better sample - more general.